# Getting A button to not reload the page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to write a program that is able to insert into three different tables, but when I execute the first button, the Insert button reloads the page and doesn't execute the query I want it too. How would I get a button that executes a query and doesn't reload the page. Right now the code will reload the page instead of submitting the query and running the code. I want to be able to have a button that runs php code without reloading the entire page, and will execute the query

```
  <html>
    <body>
     <form action="#" method="post">
       <input type="submit" class="button" name="department" value="Department" />
       <input type="submit" class="button" name="location" value="Locations" />
       <input type="submit" class="button" name="container" value="Container" />
     </form>
     <?php
                    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
                    error_reporting(E_ALL);

       if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['department'])){
      ?>
        <form action="#"  method="post">
          Office Address:<input type ='text' name='addIn'><br>
          Contact Info:<input type='text' name='conIn'><br>
          Office Hours:<input type='text' name='offIn'><br>
          Department Name:<input type='text' name='nameIn'><br>
          <button name="submit">Insert</button>
         </form>
        <?php
          if(isset($_POST['submit'])){$con=@mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 
                           'pass', 'RecyclingDB') or die("Connection error.");
              $address = $_POST['addIn'];
              $contact = $_POST['conIn'];
              $hours = $_POST['offIn'];
              $department = $_POST['nameIn'];

              $insert = "INSERT INTO Department(OfficeAddress, ContactInfo, 
                  OfficeHours, DepartmentName) VALUES('$address', '$contact', 
                  '$hours', '$department')";

              $rs = mysqli_query($con, $insert) or die ("Insert error try again.");
                            }
                    }
            ?>
           <?php
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['location'])){
           ?>
               <form action="#"  method="post">
                Location Address:<input type ='text' name='locIn'><br>
                County:<input type='text' name='couIn'><br>
                Type of Location:<input type='text' name='typeIn'><br>
                Hours:<input type='text' name='hoursIn'><br>
                Contact Info:<input type='text' name='conIn'><br>
                Department Address:<input type='text' name='depIn'><br>
                Map Link:<input type='text' name='mapIn'><br>
                <button name="submit">Insert</button> 
               </form>
            <?php
                            include_once 'insert.php';
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                   $con=@mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 
                     'RecyclingDB') or die("Connection error.");
                    $address = $_POST['locIn'];
                    $county = $_POST['couIn'];
                    $type = $_POST['typeIn'];
                    $hours = $_POST['offIn'];
                    $contact = $_POST['conIn'];
                    $depAdd = $_POST['depIn'];
                    $link = $_POST['mapIn'];
                    echo"$address, $county, $type. $hours, $contact, $depAdd, 
                    $link<br>";

                     $insert = "INSERT INTO RecyclingLocation(Address, County, 
                     TypeOfLocation, Hours, ContactInfo, DepartmentAddress, 
                      MapLink) VALUES('$address', '$county', '$type', '$hours', 
                      '$contact', '$depAdd', '$link')";
                                    echo"<br>$insert";

                      $rs = mysqli_query($con, $insert) or die ("insert error.");
                      if(mysqli_affected_rows($rs)){
                         echo"<br>Record Inserted successfully";
                      }else{
                        echo"<br>Record unable to insert, Try Again";
                                    }
                            }
                    }
          ?>
          <?php
           if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['container'])){
          ?>
              <form action="#"  method="post">
                 Size of Container:<input type ='text' name='sizeIn'><br>
                 Material:<input type='text' name='matIn'><br>
                 Number of Containers:<input type='text' name='numIn'><br>
                 Location Address:<input type='text' name='addIn'><br>
                 Cost:<input type='text' name='costIn'><br>
                 <button name="submit">Insert</button>
               </form>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                  $con=@mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 
                    'RecyclingDB') or die("Connection error.");
                  $size = $_POST['sizeIn'];
                  $material = $_POST['matIn'];
                  $number = $_POST['numIn'];
                  $location = $_POST['addIn'];
                  $cost = $_POST['costIn'];
                  echo"$size, $material, $number, $location, $cost<br>";

                  $insert="INSERT INTO Container(SizeOfContainer, Material, 
                  NumberOfContainers, LocationAddress, Cost) VALUES('$size', 
                  '$material', '$number', '$location', '$cost')";
                  echo"<br>$insert";

                  $rs = mysqli_query($con, $insert) or die ("Insert error.");
                  if(mysqli_affected_rows($rs)){
                      echo"<br>Record Inserted successfully";
                  }else{
                      echo"<br>Container inserted scuccessfullY";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                  }
                 }
                }
              ?>
         </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You need to use JavaScript and AJAX if you want to update without reloading.

Comment: Complementing what the @Barmar said, you can also do this with Javascript's `fetch API`. And the form display can also be all controlled by javascript.

Comment: @Lucas The fetch API *is* AJAX.

Comment: Sorry. I always associated `Ajax` with `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @Barmar how would I do that?

Comment: Read an AJAX tutorial and learn how to do it. This isn't a tutoring service.